# ImportError: cannot import name 'cntk_device' when using VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cntk

I followed the instructions from this [link](http://dacrook.com/cntk-vs-code-awesome/) to use VSCode for cntk.

But got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\DebugLabs\VSCodeProjects\TestPython\experiment_1.py", line 6,  in <module>
    from cntk import Trainer, cntk_device, StreamConfiguration, learning_rate_schedule, UnitType
ImportError: cannot import name 'cntk_device'
```

In both `launch.json` and `settings.json` file, I have

```
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\local\\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\\envs\\cntk-py34\\python",
```

and in `tasks.json`, I have:

```
"command": "C:\\local\\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\\envs\\cntk-py34\\python",
```

Anything I'm missing in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out. The name cntk_device does not seem to be valid. Removing it from the code resolves the error, and the program works.